# Write Nested Function Into Excel Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, nested-function

I'm trying to write the following nested formulas into cell `CY6` using VBA:

```
=IF(AND(CV6>MAX(BJ40,BJ5), CV6/MAX(BJ40,BJ5)>1.199999)," Moment Resistance Mr > Factored Moment Mf =" & ROUND(MAX(BJ40,BJ5),2)  & ". Mr/Mf =" & ROUND(CV6/MAX(BJ40,BJ5),2) & ". Proceed to Crack Control Step =>", " Moment Ratio Mr/Mf is Smaller than 1.2, Increase Steel Area. Mr/Mf=" & ROUND(CV6/BJ40,2))
```

The code I tried to use is simple

```
Range("CY6").value = " =IF(AND(CV6>MAX(BJ40,BJ5), CV6/MAX(BJ40,BJ5)>1.199999)," Moment Resistance Mr > Factored Moment Mf =" & ROUND(MAX(BJ40,BJ5),2)  & ". Mr/Mf =" & ROUND(CV6/MAX(BJ40,BJ5),2) & ". Proceed to Crack Control Step =>", " Moment Ratio Mr/Mf is Smaller than 1.2, Increase Steel Area. Mr/Mf=" & ROUND(CV6/BJ40,2)) "
```

I also tried the same thing using

```
worksheets("sheet1").range("CY6").formula= "...."
```

However, it returns a "compile error expected: end of statement" and highlights the word moment (the first one)
I think it's because of the quotation marks but I am not sure how it is supposed to work.

Comment: To add comments and the sort, you need to use an ampersand between info, e.g.:  range("cy6").formula = "=if(cond=cond,1,0)" & " words"; for additional, embedded words, you need to open/close quotations, like "=if(cond=cond,""True"",""False"")"

Comment: **(1)** Double all your quote characters within a string so that the VBA compiler knows that you want a quote character and not end your string. **(2)** User `Range("CY6").formula` to assign a formula, not `.value`

Answer (score 1):

Let's see about this...

```
=IF(AND(CV6>MAX(BJ40,BJ5), CV6/MAX(BJ40,BJ5)>1.199999)," Moment Resistance Mr > Factored Moment Mf =" & ROUND(MAX(BJ40,BJ5),2) & ". Mr/Mf =" & ROUND(CV6/MAX(BJ40,BJ5),2) & ". Proceed to Crack Control Step =>", " Moment Ratio Mr/Mf is Smaller than 1.2, Increase Steel Area. Mr/Mf=" & ROUND(CV6/BJ40,2))
```

---

```
range("cy6").formula = "=IF(AND(CV6>MAX(BJ40,BJ5), CV6/MAX(BJ40,BJ5)>1.199999),"" Moment Resistance Mr > Factored Moment Mf ="" & ROUND(MAX(BJ40,BJ5),2) & "". Mr/Mf ="" & ROUND(CV6/MAX(BJ40,BJ5),2) & "". Proceed to Crack Control Step =>"", "" Moment Ratio Mr/Mf is Smaller than 1.2, Increase Steel Area. Mr/Mf="" & ROUND(CV6/BJ40,2))"
```

Comment: OMG you guys are so fast! I thought I'd have to come back tomorrow, but no 10min. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @MohamedR did this work for you?  if so, please mark as Answered (check mark on left of post) so this is labeled appropriately in searches